# Why useState is not working properly and showing last updated content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a test application using react useState() and when i getting the image name and url using a form and then create a new object from that input and adding that object to the setImages() function then it is replace all the newly added images with the image that was added at the last. I am sharing the code that i am using to get the user input using HTML form and the function to get the new image object and code to update the state so that it can be added to array of all the images.

React code to get the use input and creating a object which is passed in the function which will add it to the array of images

```
import "./addImageButton.css"
import { ThemeContext } from "./mycontents"
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";





let formInput = {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
    like: true
}
export function AddImageButton({ addANewImages }) {
    console.log("Add image button")
    const themecontext = useContext(ThemeContext)
    console.log(themecontext)
    const addImageNameValue = useRef("null")
 
    useEffect(()=>{
        addImageNameValue.current.value = "Image Name"
        console.log("inside userref 1");
    })

    console.log("HI");
 
    function handleInputChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target.imageName);
        if (e.target.name === "imageName") {
            formInput["imageContent"] = e.target.value
        }

        if (e.target.name === "imageLink") {
            formInput["imageUrl"] = e.target.value

        }

    }
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        addANewImages(formInput)
    }



    return (
        <>

            <div style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
                <form>
                    <input placeholder="Enter Image Name"  name="imageName" ref={addImageNameValue} type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} autoFocus></input>
                    <input placeholder="Enter Image Link" name="imageLink" type="text" onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                        Add New Image
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

React code to update the state of the array of images

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./index.css"
import { AddImageButton } from "./addImageButton"
import { DeleteImage } from "./deletedImageButton.js"
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ThemeContext } from "./mycontents"
import { MyCounter } from "./mycounter"
const initialImages = [
  {
    id: 0,
    imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/05/23/23/58/moth-8013720_640.jpg",
    imageContent: "Butterfly",
    like: true

  },
  {
    id: 1,
    imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/06/11/19/09/fruit-8056663_1280.jpg",
    imageContent: "Pineapple",
    like: true

  },
]


const newtestimagesobject =    {
  imageUrl: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/06/11/19/09/fruit-8056663_1280.jpg",
  imageContent: "Pineapple",
  like: true

}




export function MyImageCard() {

  const [images, setImages] = useState(initialImages)

  function addANewImages(newImage){
    setImages(images=>[...images,newImage])

  }



  function deletingImageID(imageID) {

    const imagesAfterDelete = images.filter((value) => {


      if (value.id !== Number(imageID) || imageID === null) {
        return value
      }
    })

    console.log(imagesAfterDelete);
    setImages([...imagesAfterDelete]);
  }

  console.log("App")
  const themecontext = useContext(ThemeContext)
  console.log(themecontext)



  return (
    <>

      {
        images.map((value) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div className="imageContainer">
                <img src={value.imageUrl} alt={value.imageContent}></img>
                <br />
                <span>{value.id}. {value.imageContent} {value.like ? "✨" : ""}</span>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        })
      }
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="Vivek">
        <AddImageButton addANewImages={addANewImages}></AddImageButton>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <DeleteImage deletingImageID={deletingImageID}></DeleteImage>
      <MyCounter></MyCounter>
    </>
  )
}
```

Result of the react code as you can see the all the images added are replaced with the images added art the last except the first 5 images which are hard coded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the way you're managing the `formInput` object. Currently, you're declaring `formInput` outside of your component, which means it keeps its value between renders, so when you add a new image, all previous images in the state are updated with the last added image because they reference **the same `formInput` object**.

you should move the `formInput` inside the `handleSubmit` function, so that a **new object** is created each time the form is submitted.

```js
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formInput = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
      imageContent: addImageNameValue.current.value,
      imageUrl: e.target.imageLink.value,
      like: true,
    };

    addANewImages(formInput);
  }
```

Comment: YW, so please select my answer as the solution:)

Comment: sure, i have selected you answer.